# Makefile with headers and linker

Tags: c++, makefile, linker

I'm currently working on creating a `Makefile`for my simple c++ application.

At the moment, I'd like to compile a unique file, `main.cpp` with the following headers and linker

```
g++ main.cpp -L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/include -lboost_system
```

When I prompt this command in the terminal, everything works well. However, when put into a `Makefile`

```
SRC_FILES=main.cpp
LDLIBS=-L/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/lib -I/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.65.1/include
LD=-lboost_system

main.cpp:
    g++ main.cpp ${LDLIBS} ${LD}
```

and try to run `make -f Makefile main`, it doesn't compile.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::system::system_category()", referenced from:
      boost::asio::error::get_system_category() in main-100974.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.2 in main-100974.o
  "boost::system::generic_category()", referenced from:
      ___cxx_global_var_init in main-100974.o
      ___cxx_global_var_init.1 in main-100974.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Looks like the argument are not correctly passed.

N.B : When I try to run 
`make -f Makefile main.cpp`, the compiler tells me that `main.cpp is already up-to-date`

I assume I'm doing something wrong within the `Makefile`, but don't know what.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1):

In Makefile on the left of `:` you define target, not source:

```
main.cpp:
```

tells make how to create main.cpp if it does not exist or older than dependencies (which are on the right of : in your case is nothing). You need to give your program a name and put that as a target:

```
programname: main.cpp
      g++ main.cpp ${LDLIBS} ${LD} -o programname
```